# Read Arabic characters from webpage

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

I am trying to extract PDF links from this [LINK](https://www.moj.gov.sa/ar/Ministry/Departments/ResearchCenter/Pages/%D9%86%D8%B4%D8%B1%20%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%A3%D8%AD%D9%83%D8%A7%D9%85.aspx) 
There are three topics on this page and each is displayed by the collapse method and below each topic, there are sub-topics (months in Hijri calendar).
Below each sub-topic, there are PDF links.
How can I extract those links in organized columns: Column A would be for topics and Column B for sub-topics and Column C for the PDF links?

When trying this code

```
Sub Demo()
Dim intFF As Integer: intFF = FreeFile()
Dim iFile As String: iFile = "C:\Test\HTML.txt"
Dim html As HTMLDocument
Open iFile For Input As #intFF
strContent = Input(LOF(intFF), intFF)
Close #intFF

Set html = New HTMLDocument

With html
.body.innerHTML = strContent
Set x = .getElementsByTagName("a")
For i = 0 To x.Length - 1
    If x(i).getAttribute("data-parent") Like "*accordion1" Then
        Debug.Print x(i).innerText
    End If
    If x(i).getAttribute("data-parent") Like "*accordion2" Then
        Debug.Print x(i).innerText
    End If
Next
End With
End Sub
```

First problem the Arabic characters arenot displayed well. And another point this brings only the first main topic and there are two other main topics.

And here's the HTML in case the link doesn't work for you
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lJ7U1z3vOWz4pfbhdKi31_q674rcnuxR

Comment: 7511 PDFs. You need only the links or the PDFs itself? I have no time now but I still have to process the page structure in another way so that columns A and B are filled correctly. Besides, I have now tried the Internet Explorer. But it has problems with a script on the page and it takes very long. If I manage it I will take care of it again in the evening.

Comment: @Zwenn Thanks a lot for your interest. Take your time. I am not in a hurry.

Comment: @Zwenn Any updates?

Comment: @Qharr Can you have a look, please?

Comment: @omegastripes Can you have a look, please?